# Install pgadmin in debian server

Tags: debian, postgresql

I have got pgAdminIII-1.14 source code from the official website.

Now I'm trying to compile it, on a Debian Squeeze machine.

At first I did:

```
./configure
```

and I got this error:

```
configure: error: you must specify a valid PostgreSQL 8.4+ installation with --with-pgsql=DIR
```

I don't know which one is the directory it requires, I tried with:

```
/usr/lib/postgresql/9.1/bin
```

which is the directory in which I have "psql", but it is not the good one.

How can I solve?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Probably you have to set `--with-pgsql=/usr/lib/postgresql/9.1`

How did you installed postgresql server? Using repository or from sources?

On the other hand this problem may occour while you are missing pg_config (which ,.configure is looking for)

Please execute `which pg_config` and if it's missing - install additional pacakges
`sudo apt-get install libpq-dev`

If it doesn't help you - try moving/copy/link `/usr/bin/pg_config` to `/usr/lib/postgresql/9.1/bin/.`

Then probably 
`configure: error: Could not find your wxWidgets installation. You might need to use the --with-wx=DIR configure option` error will occure.

Fix it with
`apt-get install libwxgtk2.8-dev libwxgtk2.8-dbg`

Next one is `configure: error: Could not find your libxml2 installation. You might need to use the --with-libxml2=DIR configure option`

Fix - `apt-get install libxml2-dev`

Once again - `configure: error: Could not find your libxslt installation. You might need to use the --with-libxslt=DIR configure option`

Fix - `apt-get install libxslt1-dev`

After that make fails

```
gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I..  -DDATA_DIR=\"/usr/local/pgadmin3/share/pgadmin3/\" -I../pgadmin/include -I/usr/include    /postgresql -I/usr/include/postgresql/9.1/server -I/usr/include/postgresql -DSSL -DHAVE_CONNINFO_PARSE -I/usr/lib/wx/include/gtk2-unicode-release-2.8 -I/usr/include/wx-2.8 -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -D_LARGE_FILES -D__WXGTK__ -DEMBED_XRC -I/usr/include/libxml2 -I/usr/include/libxml2  -O2 -MT keywords.o -MD -MP -MF .deps/keywords.Tpo -c -o keywords.o `test -f './db/keywords.c' || echo './'`./db/keywords.c
./db/keywords.c:33:27: fatal error: parser/kwlist.h: Nie ma takiego pliku ani katalogu compilation terminated. make[3]: *** [keywords.o]
Błąd 1 make[3]: Opuszczenie katalogu `/home/pkieszcz/pgadmin3-1.14.3/pgadmin' make[2]: *** [all] Błąd 2
 make[2]: Opuszczenie katalogu `/home/pkieszcz/pgadmin3-1.14.3/pgadmin'
 make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Błąd 1 make[1]: Opuszczenie katalogu
 `/home/pkieszcz/pgadmin3-1.14.3' make: *** [all] Błąd 2
```

Make parser folder and wget this file here - http://www.markmcfadden.net/files/kwlist.h

Then finally - make and make install went well.

TL, DR;

```
apt-get install libxslt1-dev libxml2-dev libwxgtk2.8-dev libwxgtk2.8-dbg libpq-dev 
cp /usr/bin/pg_config /usr/lib/postgresql/9.1/bin/. 
./configure 
mkdir parser
cd parser 
wget http://www.markmcfadden.net/files/kwlist.h 
make 
make install
```

Comment: No, I tried but it's not right.

Comment: Hope my edited answer will help you.